# Getting syntax error at or near "IF" PSQL Trigger/Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I can't find where the syntax error is for this psql function.

I have tried debugging and looking at other online examples to make sure my syntax is consistent.[image]

Comment: Don't post text as images

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: The code is not valid plpgsql, you don't even mention the language

Comment: Look at [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-structure.html).